# can I have an iterator without hasNext()? - Q from school project

Tags: java, iterator, iteration

I've  got a task to program an iterator that brings back the next letter in the ABC:

if my string is `a` -> `b`

if it's `ad` -> `ae`

if it's `Z` -> `aa`

if it's `az` -> `aA`

if it's `aZ` -> `ba`

if it's `ZZ` -> `aaa`

and so...

I just can't understand what should be in my `hasNext()`. The teacher told us they won't check us with great numbers of letters so `<Max Vaule` is unnecessary.

the only thing I can think of is not using this at all but I don't know if I should or how to write that I'm not using it.

Comment: I do not get what you mean by "*if my string is ...*". An iterator is something obtained through an object. The methods of an interator do not take parameters (except for `forEachRemaining(...)`). --- As it seems, the interator described produces an endless sequence, hence `hasNext()` would always return `true`.

Comment: Are you talking about some kind of iterator, or about `Iterator`? The latter isn't exactly designed to answer questions like *"what's next after x?"*

Comment: is it case sensitive ? does aZ and az have next value as aa ?

Comment: simply return true for hasNext.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are trying to make your own implementation of the Iterator of java.util interface. If  you are willing to do so, the `hasNext()` method should return always `true`, because there will be always an next element because the Iterator is infinite. Read the JavaDocs of `hasNext()`:

> Returns true if the iteration has more elements. (In other words, returns true if next() would return an element rather than throwing an exception.)
> https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html

Code example:

```
@Override
public boolean hasNext() {
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take based on the information provided. The `hasNext()` returns a `false` indicating that you are done, or `true` if you should continue.  So you should return `true` until you reach the value (or it gets changed) and then return `false`.  The last returned value is the one you want to use. If you don't return `false` eventually, you will never finish if you keep calling `hasNext()`, waiting for completion.

In this case, it seems `hasNext()` will always be called twice since it only takes one change to alter the sequence.

Now, if you are to continue changing the last letter from a given initial value (which wasn't clear in your question), then you should return `true`.

But what do you do if you keep on returning true and hit `AZ`?  What is the next letter?  Do you wrap around and return `BA` and keep iterating?  What about `ZZ`?  Would that then be `AAA`?  Perhaps when you run out of letters (e.g. reach a `Z`) you should return `false` next time thru.  Only you can answer that based on your intimate understanding of your assignment.

One final thought. If `hasNext()` always returns `true`, there is no reason to call it. Everthing required can be handled within `next()` or some other method.  Therefore, one would not even need an iterator implementation.

Answer (score 0):

When we talk about an iterator, we are talking about `Iterator` class' implementation. This implementation **must** contain two methods: `hasNext()` and `next()`.

According to the specification, `hasNext()` should retrieve `true` only if `next()` will retrieve a result. In other words, if `hasNext()` retrieves `false`, then there are no more items in the iterator.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    Iterator<String> it = new SequenceIterator(2);

    while (it.hasNext())
        System.out.println(it.next());
}

public static final class SequenceIterator implements Iterator<String> {

    private final char[] arr;

    public SequenceIterator(int maxLength) {
        arr = new char[maxLength];
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        for (char ch : arr)
            if (ch != 'Z')
                return true;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public String next() {
        if (!hasNext())
            throw new NoSuchElementException();

        inc(arr.length - 1);

        return new String(arr).trim();
    }

    private boolean inc(int i) {
        boolean res = true;

        if (i < 0)
            res = false;
        else if (arr[i] == '\0')
            arr[i] = 'a';
        else if ((arr[i] >= 'a' && arr[i] < 'z') || (arr[i] >= 'A' && arr[i] < 'Z'))
            arr[i]++;
        else if (arr[i] == 'z')
            arr[i] = 'A';
        else if (res = inc(i - 1))
            arr[i] = 'a';

        return res;
    }

}
```